# How to use C++ getopt_long() if I have more than 26 options?

Tags: c++

This is a rather hypothetical question, but let's say I have 3 long parameters that begin with the same letter.

```
--parse or -p
--prune or -r
--pivot or -i
```

Eventually I'll start running out of single letters that make sense, more over, it's hard assign something meaningful in [GNU getopt_long()](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Getopt-Long-Option-Example.html#Getopt-Long-Option-Example) configuration.

```
{"parase", no_argument,       0, 'p'},
{"prune",  no_argument,       0, 'r'},
{"pivot",  required_argument, 0, 'i'}
```

What is the best practice in these situations?

Comment: How about `getopt_long_only()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a choice of uppercase, as well as lowercase, giving you 52 short options, however many programs that accept long options don't even bother assigning short options to some options, forcing the user to use the long options only, which OK.

Comment: Can you give a code example of a case where you specify only long options? Because when I look at the example given in the [GNU manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt-Long-Option-Example.html#Getopt-Long-Option-Example), I don't see how to do the switch. Thanks.

Comment: @wfoolhill GNU tar for example has the options `--backup`, `--checkpoint`, `--force-local` and many others, that have no short option equivalent.

Comment: thanks, but [GNU tar](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/tar.git/tree/src/tar.c#n385) uses [argp](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argp.html#Argp) and not getopt, and it's pretty hard to understand from its source code how argp works. Whatsoever, I still didn't find any short example showing how to use only long options.

Comment: @wfoolhill Can't you just pass 0 as the last field in `struct option`?

Comment: If I follow the getopt_long [example](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt-Long-Option-Example.html#Getopt-Long-Option-Example) but I want to specify a long option "param" with a required argument (and not with a flag), gcc complains because "c" used in "switch (c)" should be a single letter. See an example [here](http://ideone.com/yllaO).

Comment: @wfoolhill Start a new question.

Comment: you're right, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213071/in-c-how-to-use-only-long-options-with-a-required-argument) it is.

Answer (score 7):

You don't have to use printable characters for the `val` member. Moreover, it's `int`, not `char`. It should just assist you with identifying the option. (meaning, you don't have to have corresponding shorty).

Comment: +1 This is the correct answer.  This gives you sizeof(int) options.

Comment: @qwerty9967, `sizeof(int)` isn't much ;-) It's 2 power 8*sizeof(int) ;-)

Comment: @Krelin it's quite a bit larger than 52. Have you ever written a program that needed more than 2 pow 8*sizeof(int) option?

Comment: @qwerty9967, what I'm trying to say is that I'd expect `sizeof(int)` to be like 4 on a 64-bit architecture. Which is, again, not much. Definitely you don't have to use all the gazillions of options just because you can.

Comment: @qwerty9967, in short, you probably meant something like maxint (which is, again, around `1<<(8*sizeof int)`), not the size of integer in bytes.

Comment: @Krelin ... yup I'm an idiot.  I meant maxint, not sizeof(int).  My main point is that your answer should have been selected.

Comment: @qwerty9967, good that I made it clear. As for selecting — it's up to the one who asked. That's why there is a green checkmark *and* votes ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The digits 0-9 can be used to. Imagine a data compression program which would either accept `-compression=[0-9]`, or just `-[0-9]` (I don't know if this works with getopt, though).

Also, uppercase can be used, too.

I understand that's a hypothetical question, but with so many options, the program probably does too much or needs a configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to take a look at [boost program options](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/program_options.html). It is a general-purpose library for getting command line arguments. Very easy and pleasant to use.

Comment: Imho this is more a comment than an answer.