# In C++, how to use only long options with a required argument?

Tags: c++, getopt

In a C++ program, I would like to have a "long-only" option with a required argument. Below is my minimal example using [getopt_long()](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt-Long-Option-Example.html#Getopt-Long-Option-Example), but it's not working:

```
#include <getopt.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void help (char ** argv)
{
  cout << "`" << argv[0] << "` experiments with long options." << endl;
}

void parse_args (int argc, char ** argv, int & verbose, int & param)
{
  int c = 0;
  while (1)
  {
    static struct option long_options[] =
      {
        {"help", no_argument, 0, 'h'},
        {"verbose", required_argument, 0, 'v'},
        {"param", required_argument, 0, 0}
      };
    int option_index = 0;
    c = getopt_long (argc, argv, "hv:",
                     long_options, &option_index);
    cout << "c=" << c << endl;
    if (c == -1)
      break;
    switch (c)
    {
    case 0:
      if (long_options[option_index].flag != 0)
        break;
      printf ("option %s", long_options[option_index].name);
      if (optarg)
        printf (" with arg %s", optarg);
      printf ("\n");
      break;
    case 'h':
      help (argv);
      exit (0);
    case 'v':
      verbose = atoi(optarg);
      break;
    case 'param':
      param = atoi(optarg);
      break;
    case '?':
      abort ();
    default:
      abort ();
    }
  }
}

int main (int argc, char ** argv)
{
  int verbose = 0;
  int param = 0;
  parse_args (argc, argv, verbose, param);
  cout << "verbose=" << verbose << " param=" << param << endl;
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I compile it with this command (gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 Red Hat 4.1.2-46):

```
g++ -Wall test.cpp
```

It tells me this:

```
test.cpp:44:10: warning: character constant too long for its type
```

And here is the result:

```
$ ./a.out -v 2 --param 3
c=118
c=0
option param with arg 3
c=-1
verbose=2 param=0
```

I tried to make it work on [ideone](http://ideone.com/yllaO) but it doesn't even recognize the option `-v`.

As indicated by trojanfoe in his [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8169291/597069) of another question, it should be possible to use "long-only" options because GNU tar does it. However, GNU tar uses [argp](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argp.html#Argp) and I have difficulty understanding its [source code](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/tar.git/tree/src/tar.c#n385).

Could someone give me a minimal example that works, with GNU `getopt_long()` or `argp()`?

Comment: You might want to consider using [Boost.Program_options](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/program_options.html) instead.

Comment: @JerryCoffin thanks for the tip, I would prefer using argp, especially since it seems to be possible to solve my problem with it (see the GNU tar example)

Comment: It is undoubtedly possible to make `argp` do the job. Boost just does it a lot better and more cleanly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. According to the example code (your link), the final option defined in the struct must be `{0,0,0,0}`. I recommend changing the definition to

   ```
   static struct option long_options[] =
     {
       {"help", no_argument, 0, 'h'},
       {"verbose", required_argument, 0, 'v'},
       {"param", required_argument, 0, 0},
       {0,0,0,0}
     };
   ```
2. (And more importantly,) you must include code that actually processes the "param" option. You do that in the `'0'` case:

   ```
   case 0:
     if (long_options[option_index].flag != 0)
       break;
     if (strcmp(long_options[option_index].name,"param") == 0)
       param = atoi(optarg);
     break;
   ```

As you can see I use the `strcmp` function to compare the strings; for that you need to `#include <cstring>`. By the way, you also need `#include <cstdio>` for your use of `printf`.

With these changes in place, the program worked correctly for me (tested on GCC 4.5.1).

Answer (score 5):

In your case statement, you are using:

```
case 'param':
```

which is giving you the warning, because compiler expects a single character in that place.

Comment: You can, but it is compiler-specific how it is interpreted.  You're right about it being the source of the compiler warning.

Comment: @Thiruvalluvar thanks, but I'm not really worried by the warning since it will be disappear once someone will find the solution to my problem, namely "how to use a long-only option".

Comment: If you want to use string as a parameter, then you can use str1.compare(str2) and pass its return value to the swtich-case. @JonathanLeffler edited it now.

Comment: @Thiruvalluvar I didn't know it was possible, how would you do that concretely? (sorry but I'm not a professional C++ programmer...)

Comment: getopt_long returns an `int` and you are using its value in the switch-case. But your case statements check for chars. This is what you intend to do?

Comment: @Thiruvalluvar `getopt_long` returns an `int` but it corresponds to a `char` (see the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/)). For instance, when `c=118`, the short option is `v`. Whatsoever, I found a solution to my problem, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, I realized that I should check the value of `option_index` when `c` has the value `0`, like this. Such a case is not in the GNU libc examples, so here it is:

```
switch (c)
{
case 0:
  if (long_options[option_index].flag != 0)
    break;
  if (option_index == 2)
  {
    param = atoi(optarg);
    break;
  }
case 'h':
  help (argv);
  exit (0);
case 'v':
  verbose = atoi(optarg);
  break;
case '?':
  abort ();
default:
  abort ();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use 'flag' member value defined in struct option.

Setup your options like below:

```
int param_flag = 0;

{"param", required_argument, &param_flag, 1}
```

Then;

```
case 0:
    if (param_flag == 1) {
        do_something;
    }
```

See man getopt_long for details about struct option.